# Silverstripe 3.3: how to translate date month variable in a template?

Tags: php, translation, silverstripe

On my page I have a date variable. I wish to translate it's shortened month name by locale (in my case Lithuanian).

I've set up the translations in langed/lang/lt_LT.yml:

```
Month:
    Jan: 'Sau'
    Feb: 'Vas'
    Mar: 'Kov'
    Apr: 'Bal'
    ...
```

And in my template when I put

```
$Date.Format(M d)
```

It gives the month and day always in English, no matter the locale (ex. "Apr 18", I need "Bal 18" in this case).

I have attempted to try to put the variable of Month into translation quotes of .ss template:

```
<%t Month.$Date.Format('M') %>
```

But it doesn't work. It throws an error:

"[User Error] Uncaught SSTemplateParseException: Parse error in template on line 16. Error was: Malformed opening block tag t. Perhaps you have tried to use operators?"

Can anyone please explain to me how am I doing this wrong?

Comment: what have you set in your _config? does this this help?

`i18n::set_locale('lt_LT');`

an in template `$Date.FormatI18N('%d b%')`

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention... The page is translatable. I need an English and a Lithuanian version of it and their respective translations.

Comment: What module do you use for translations? @munomono gave you the correct way to get international formatting for dates.

Comment: I used the localdate module

Comment: @PavelŠliachtovič If it doesn't work what I suggest, check what locales are on your server `locale -a` and install if needed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [$Date.FormatI18N('%b')](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-Date.html#_FormatI18N) which utilizes [strftime()](http://php.net/strftime) which in turn needs your locale installed on the server to translate it. If not you just get the english (or default) locale.

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/wernerkrauss/e0f9104c3fb8f71960c3) for an extension to get the current locale in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've implemented this is put a function on the controller:

```
public function MonthForVar($var) {
    return _t("Month.$var");
}
```

and then you can call `$MonthForVar($Date)` in your template. Don't forget if you're doing it in a loop to go `$Up.MonthForVar($Date)`

** Should add that wmk's answer is better for date format however I was lead here from Google when I'm trying to translate something non-date related, in which case this should work.